# Include child records in to_indexed_json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tire

In Invoice model i using to_indexed_json method

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
      invoice_number: invoice_number,
      state: state,
  }.to_json
end
```

I am including invoice_line_items(child) attributes like this

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
      invoice_number: invoice_number,
      state: state,
      invoice_line_items: { description: invoice_line_items.description }
  }.to_json
end
```

Now by creating invoice i am getting this error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `item_description' for #<Array:0xd748eb8>:
```

How can i include invoice_line_items attributes in to_indexed_json method??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `invoice_line_items` is an `Array`, you're trying to invoke the method `description` on an `Array` not on your `LineItem` object. Try this:

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
      invoice_number: invoice_number,
      state: state,
      invoice_line_items: invoice_line_items.map { |li| { description: li.description } }
  }.to_json
end
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you might want to look into something like [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). It basically offers you a simple DSL to render JSON as views and keeps you from managing huge hash structures. There's also a good [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) for it.